# Not to Use Spring Security Authentication?

Tags: java, security, spring, authentication, spring-security

Spring Security 3 reference says that:

> 5.3 Authentication
>
> Spring Security can participate in many different authentication
>   environments. While we recommend people use Spring Security for
>   authentication and not integrate with existing Container Managed
>   Authentication, it is nevertheless supported - as is integrating with
>   your own proprietary authentication system.

I couldn't understand what to do for security according to that text. Can anybody explain me?

**LINK:** http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation:

> Spring Security can participate in many different authentication
>   environments.

It supports different, external authentication systems like Microsoft Active Directory, Single-sign-on systems, etc.

> While we recommend people use Spring Security for authentication and not integrate with existing Container Managed Authentication,[...]

It is not recommended to activate container managed security modules, like Tomcat authentication function (J2EE security).

> [...] it is nevertheless supported[...]

as defined - it is supported.

> [...] - as is integrating with your own proprietary authentication system.

I suppose this references back to quote #1, they support proprietary authentication systems as well, e.g. home-grown systems.

Comment: So does it mean I should use Spring Security for authentication and not anything else like Tomcat? Sorry but I am so new to Spring and Spring Security.

Comment: @kamaci: Yeah, this is my understanding. I must admit I did never use it that way. Did not they do recommend to **not** use container authentication.

Comment: I think the point may be to not use *both* SS and container-based security; use one or the other. It's not clear *why* that's the recommendation.

Comment: Sorry but where can I find information about container based security? I use Tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat's documentation is a good starting point: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html

Comment: This document explains it well:http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0726-security.html?page=1